# How can I send some key to process id in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to send some key like F1, Q, W, E, ETC to process id how to do that ??

processid.py

```
import psutil

process_name = 'notepad.exe'

def pidCheck(self):
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        if process_name in proc.name():
            pid = proc.pid
```

I already got pid please help